# Accessing properties of ember-data through relationship (Not in the template)

Tags: properties, ember.js, parent-child, ember-data, has-many

I want to stress that this problem only occurs outside of a template, such as when I try to access properties of related objects while in a controller, unit test, etc. Rendering the template seem to get the property well and work as expected.

Here is a simple example in JS Bin with a failing test http://jsbin.com/ihumuk/4/edit which repros my problem. The passing test asserts that the property is accessible and rendered in the template as expected. The failing test shows that I get `null` when I try to access the property with `get`. Really nothing fancy here but I don't understand why it's returning `null`.

Here is the application part of the JS Bin example:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Foo.find();
  }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()
});

App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string"),

  /**
   * The subject under test
   */
  childName: function() {
    return this.get("child.name");
  }.property("child.name"),

  child: DS.belongsTo("App.Bar")
});

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string")
});

App.Foo.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Fred",
  child: 3
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Barney",
  child: 4
}];

App.Bar.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 3,
  name: "Pebbles"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Bam Bam"
}];
```

This passes.

```
test("Child name is rendered", function() {
  expect(1);

  visit("/").then(function() {
    ok(find("div:contains(Pebbles)").length);
  });
});
```

This fails.

```
test("Child name is accessed", function() {
  expect(2);
  var foo = App.Foo.find(1);
  equal(foo.get("childName"), "Pebbles");
  equal(foo.get("child.name"), "Pebbles");
});
```

This has to be something simple/stupid like forgetting a character or something, but I think I've driven myself too far into frustration to think clearly for a while. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `then` to know when the data is loaded

```
asyncTest("Child name is accessed", function() {
  expect(2);
  // load the data from server
  App.Foo.find(1).then(function(foo) {
    // the child id is 3, we need to fetch the remaining data
    // and this is async, because of the ajax request    
    foo.get("child").then(function(child) {      
      equal(child.get("name"), "Pebbles");
      // childName call child.name, but since the 
      // data is loaded, isn't necessary to use a second then
      equal(foo.get("childName"), "Pebbles");
      start();
    });
  });  
});
```

In ember data, like major of the orm's, the data is lazy loaded, for relationships. This is because, isn't needed to return all loaded object graph, let's leave the user ask for what it want, and then load.

Because some implementations are async, like: websql, indexeddb, ajax, websockets etc. The interface of ember-data is async, so you need to use the `then` method to know when the data is loaded or failed.

The things work in your template, because it are binding aware. Even when the change are async, it will be finished later, and the bindings will be notified and updated.

I have updated your demo, and the tests pass http://jsbin.com/eqojaj/1/edit